# Built-in function scipy.signal.savgol_filter returns error

Tags: python, filter, scipy

I am trying to filter a data set using the `scipy.signal.savgol_filter` function, but I get the error

```
TypeError: expected x and y to have same length
```

when I try to assign the data in a new list.

What is stranger is that just before my last computation everything worked as intended, but now I get this. I have tried to create an empty list the size of the filtered one, but I get the same error.

Here is that part of my code:

```
import scipy as sc
import scipy.signal
Cf = sc.signal.savgol_filter(x=C, window_length=299, polyorder=3)
```

where `C` is a well defined list of float type numbers.

Comment: C is a list, or an array?  Maybe C is not the right type for this method.  Can you add some sample data of C?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I get the error that you reported if the `window_length` is greater than the length of `C` (e.g. `savgol_filter([3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9], window_length=7, polyorder=3)`).

In SciPy 1.0.0, the cryptic error message has been replaced with a more informative message:

```
ValueError: If mode is 'interp', window_length must be less than
or equal to the size of x.
```

Comment: Indeed, that is the problem. It had previously worked because my list C was very large.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7):

The error message is confusing. In my case the problem was with the input array. It was in the following form:

```
x = np.array([[3], 
              [1],
              [4],
              [1], 
              [5], 
              [9]])
```

Supplying it flattened by [`np.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) solved the problem:

```
>>> np.ravel(x)
array([3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9])
```

Comment: Indeed, a more explanatory error would have been welcome. +1.